# iOS custom keyboard with horizontal sliding

Tags: ios, keyboard

I'm creating a custom keyboard in iOS, and so far I haven't had too many obstacles except trying to create horizontal sliding like the the standard keyboard has for the emojis, for example. I only need to create two "pages", where the iOS standard keyboard has 9 or so. I'm using a xib for the view.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
~Rye

Comment: Have a look at [app extension guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you want to implement a UIScrollView with multiple horizontal paging. Check [this project](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView) out to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That definitely guides me in the right direction.